# How to clone repository from git to separate directories?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, repository

Good day!

I have a problem. There is a project in Azure DevOps where git repository is located. The repository contains 2 folders. When I worked in TFSVS, I could map server folders to local through workspaces and the repository is downloaded into distinct directories.

Is there a way to perform the same procedure using Git functionality in Visual Studio 2019? Or is there at least a way to do so anyway? I mean to clone the repository into distinct catalogues or move them after clone process, because it is necessary to have one folder in a specific directory (which is not empty) and the other folder with projects can be anywhere?

**Example:

*The repository:***

> [project]/folder1
> [project]/folder2

And I have to clone as a ***following way:***

> K:/x/p/q/folder1
> C:/x/p/q/folder2

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just clone the repository twice. You cannot clone a git repository in parts like with other version control systems (e.g. SVN). Even a partial checkout is not normally possible.

Comment: However, how can I connect them? In VS for example, I can just clone it at once. I wanted to make some symlinks after cloning, is it suitable solution?

Comment: I don't think so, but to give an accurate answer, please [edit] your question and include details about your project structure

Comment: Agree with @PMF above, clone it twice into two separate folders and perhaps use [**Git Sparse Checkout**](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)

Comment: Isn't sparse suits only for filtering specific folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could solve it by myself. I created symbolic links in necessary folders to the folders in my repository and this helped.
I want also thank everyone who was trying to help me here.

**The solution is suitable for everyone who migrates to git in Microsoft Dynamics 365 AX**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I already see the full picture, but it looks like what you really need is two repositories. Your projects seem independent, so *make* them independent. Split the git repository into two, so you can checkout each one to wherever you need it.

Comment: Well, I had such an idea. However, these folders are located in the same repository and what is more, I have to work with it through the Visual Studio. The reason why I have to place them into specific directory is that the folder one contains the important files for the environment that must be placed into specific directory while the second one is for projects. What is more when we code, the files are changed in both directories